# Controls invisible when changing height

Tags: c#, windows

```
int Height=Convert.ToInt32(float.Parse(txtHeight.Text))
```

The above line of code was executed the windows form shrinking to small size and controls are not visible, instead it is causing my form to close.

Comment: Put a try and catch block, what is the exception?

Comment: Your question doesn't explain why your form would close, but then I can't understand the convert to float to int either

Comment: Set a minimum height in your form or wrap the above line in an if block to ensure it won't shrink the form to an unusable height.

Comment: I'm having troubles understanding the question.

Comment: @santhosh kumar vadlamani , this is krishna kishore ... you get a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Considering `float.Parse(txtHeigth.Text))`, most probabbly there is a parsing exception.

First:  use  `TryParse(..)`

Second:  specify `Culture` *always*.

So using method [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/3s27fasw.aspx) (example)

```
var result = 0; 

if(float.TryParse(txtHeight.Text, 
              NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result)) {
   //Conversion succeed 
}
```

Thhird: at least from the code provided, don't see a sence of *first* converting text to `float`, and *after* to `int`. Convert it immediately to the desired destination format, so `int`.